# AngularFire | Make dynamic URL with post ID

Tags: facebook, angular, url, firebase, angularfire

I recently discovered Firebase and I'm currently creating an e-sport website using **AngularFire**. 
In this one, users can sign up with Facebook, search and create video games tournaments (LAN) with several filters (game, location ...).

At the moment, I only did the authentication and the routing, but before make more code, **I would like to know if it is possible to create dynamic URL with a post ID and the same template for each post**.
For example, I create a LAN (ID : 458) and the url is http://mywebsite/lan/458.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure if this is angular2 if so did you work through the routing tutorial ?    this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedHero.id]); should do the trick if i understand correctly. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Comment: I'm using angular1 and I made my rooting with this guide : https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md